# Main class in clojure, leiningan (Conway's game of life)

Tags: syntax, clojure, conways-game-of-life

Hi guys! I'm running Conway's game of life - but I think I had to modify the original version here: https://github.com/sebastianbenz/clojure-game-of-life to reference `field.clj` (rather than `run.clj`) in the `project.clj` file. After doing so, I can start the game by running

```
repl> (run-game)
```

However, it crashes on this method, which has no comments regarding input arguments.

Thus, my question is: what does this form (appear to do) from a Clojure syntax perspective?

```
(defn run-game
  ([engine seed]
    (run-game engine seed
      {:columns 50 :rows 50 :speed 500 :cellsize 10}))
  ([engine seed options]
    (let [panel (field-panel engine seed options)
          frame (field-frame panel)
          timer (Timer. (options :speed) panel)]
      (.start timer))))
```

UPDATE *_*

- Why is "[engine-seed]" nested in a parentheses?
- Why is this function recursive?
- any other syntax level insights to how this function is designed?

Comment: Aha - now I see --- this is a polymorphic function... So depending on how many args are I putted, a different functional implementation is triggered .  I did not realize that you could define multiple functions polymorphically using this syntax.

Comment: I don't think this is related to how polymorphism is usually defined. It's just a function with an optional argument.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but it basically defines a function that either takes `engine` and `seed` arguments or `engine`, `seed` and `options` arguments.

If the `option` argument isn't specified, the function creates a default map `{:columns 50 :rows 50 :speed 500 :cellsize 10}` and calls the second form.

You'll have to look at the code to determine what `engine` and `seed` should be set to.

Then you can call it as:

```
(run-game engine seed)
```

or

```
(run-game engine seed {:columns 75 :rows 75 :speed 750 :cellsize 15})
```

Does that help?

Comment: I'm not sure how these arguments are being used--- so this isn't much help... :( I understand that the program takes 2 arguments.... But having trouble interpreting what the run-game function's syntax is doing... Looking for specifics on how the function is working and how its delegating the arguments. Also wondering why there are no leading []s after the defn function name.

Comment: Upvote for clarifying that my question was not precise enough.